# Octave Psychtoolbox can't find Screen.mex despite being first directory in path

Tags: octave, psychtoolbox

I have attempted to install Psychtoolbox for Octave on Windows 10, per the [installation instructions](http://psychtoolbox.org/download#Windows). Before the installation completes, I get this warning:

```
Screen() failed to work for some reason:

Check the troubleshooting instructions on our Wiki (Download section
and FAQ section, maybe also the Bugs section).

You may need to delete (or rename) the following DLL files in your Octave-4.4.1 installations
bin folder to make this work, then restart Octave:
C:\Octave\4.4.1\bin\libglib-2.0.0.dll
C:\Octave\4.4.1\bin\libgmodule-2.0.0.dll
C:\Octave\4.4.1\bin\opengl32.dll

Once you manage to fix the problem (simply type 'AssertOpenGL' to verify
that stuff works now), you do not need to run the installation routine again,
but can start working immediately.
```

I had already deleted the named DLL files, which I confirmed. I then ran `AssertOpenGL` and received this error:

```
Last Error: could not find library or dependencies: D:\Coding\PTB\Psychtoolbox\PsychBasic\Octave4WindowsFiles64\Screen.mex
```

Simply calling `Screen` directly gives this error:

```
error: library open failed: D:\Coding\PTB\Psychtoolbox\PsychBasic\Octave4WindowsFiles64\Screen.mex
```

However, the directory containing Screen.mex is at the very top of my path:

```
Octave's search path contains the following directories:

.
D:\Coding\PTB\Psychtoolbox\PsychBasic\Octave4WindowsFiles64
D:\Coding\PTB\Psychtoolbox
<etc>
```

As such, the solution to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661196/why-is-matlabs-psychtoolbox-failing-to-detect-the-screen-mexfile-when-running-a) is of no use. What might I be able to do to correctly configure PTB on Octave?

Comment: Get the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) and see if any dependencies of the MEX-file are missing. Just open the MEX-file in the Dependency Walker program, it’ll tell you if anything is wrong.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, I'll check that out.

Comment: As far as I can see the .mex files are precompiled. Are you sure they match your system 32/64 bit. You didn't mention your windoze version

Answer (score 0):

What version of gstreamer are you using? I had a similar problem recently and fixed it by installing gstreamer 1.14.4. The latest version of gstreamer will not work, nor will versions earlier than 1.14.4.

Comment: Please add information why versions earlier or later won't work in this context. Its rather vague "install 1.14.4 without a little context.

Comment: I don't know why. @ZF007